# Using scatter_nd_add op inside a while loop?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to do a `tf.scatter_nd_add` inside a `tf.while` loop. It gives me an error message though.

```
TypeError: 'ScatterNdAdd' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)
```

It seems like the way that while loops work is that it changes the input variable from being of type `tf.Variable` to having some other type. Is it possible to do a scatter_nd_add op inside a while loop?

Here's a code excerpt:

```
self.hough = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((num_points, num_points), dtype=tf.float32),
                             name='hough')
self.i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i, hough: tf.less(i, tf.squeeze(tf.shape(self.img_x)))
b = lambda i, hough: self.ProcessPixel(i, hough)
self.r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [self.i, self.hough], back_prop=False)
```

This is the body of the loop:

```
def ProcessPixel(self, i, hough):
        pixel_x, pixel_y = self.img_x[self.i], self.img_y[self.i]
        result = self.GetLinesThroughPixel(pixel_x, pixel_y)
        idx = tf.stack([tf.range(num_points, dtype=tf.int64), result])
        pixel_val = self.img[tf.to_int32(pixel_x), tf.to_int32(pixel_y)]

        print type(hough)
        updated_hough = tf.scatter_nd_add(hough, tf.transpose(idx),
                                          updates=pixel_val * tf.ones(num_points))

        return tf.add(i, 1), updated_hough
```

Comment: Could you post some more of your code please? Specifically the while_loop and the inputs you're passing in.

Comment: @AvishkarBhoopchand I added a code sample. I'm not sure it will help resolve the issue though.

Comment: Instead of doing the scatter_add to the variable in the loop, why not just accumulate the result and apply it at the end? So something like ```updated_hough = hough + tf.scatter_nd(...) ``` and at the end of your while loop do a tf.assign(self.hough, self.r[1]) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting or that it would work. Can you explain more?